# linq2sql: can't fetch object 2nd time

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

In my application one object is fetched from DB with query like this:

```
IList<MyObject> objects = GetContext()
    .GetTable()
    .Where(obj=>obj.ParentId==iParentId)
    .ToList()
    ;
```

After getting from db data from 'objects' lists is copied into list of business objects. Later I need to update this object with new data from business entity. For this purpose I need to get 'DB entity' from database, update it's fields and call 'SubmitChanges()'.

The problem is that '2nd fetch from DB' doesn't work. The following query:

```
MyObject objectToBeUpdated = GetContext()
    .GetTable()
    .Where(obj=>obj.Id==iObjectId)
    .SingleOrDefault()
    ;
```

returns null..

Q1. Why I get 'null' here? Can this be caused that I need to 'release' the 1st entity in some way? Or I need to remember the original entity (don't fetch it from DB again) and update it?

Q2. How to get entity 2nd time?

P.S. Actually, I would rather will on preventing 2nd fetch, but it would be good to know the reason what is wrong here.

Thanks a lot.

P.S. I'm using MSSQL 2005, VS2008, Linq2sql.

Comment: Are you sure you requested the same object?

Comment: 100% yes, it is the same

Comment: Are both queries being made on the same datacontext instance?  If so, the second query should be returning the exact same entity instance as the first query, even if it was modified between queries.  If the second query was **not** on the same datacontext instance, then you should be getting a clean copy of the same entity (as you were expecting).  In this case, I would suggest using SQL Server Profiler to capture the SQL being generated in the second query, run it manually, and go from there.  That usually leads you to the true problem.

Comment: Queries are different (I thought is is obvious). The 1st query returns list of object, and the 2nd - 1 object only. Context is also the same in both cases. Profiler - good idea, will see what can I do there... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it returns null becoz there's no record that satisfies your where clause. Since you call SingleOrDefault() it returns you the default object that's null. Instead if you call Single() you will get an exception. Double check you actually have records in the db that meet the condition

Comment: But i did 2 operations in a row. The 1st - returned object, the 2nd - didn't. And object was not deleted between these 2 transactions.